# Inserting floating text near decision tree arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, nodes, arrows, tikz-trees

How do I insert Yes and No beside the solid arrows?

I tried putting `node [near end, right] {Yes}` after each node and child declaration but this just messes up the flow of the decision tree.

### Code

```
    \noindent
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
      \centering 
      \sffamily

      \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=4.25cm]
      \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2.25cm]
      \tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=4.25cm]
      \tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2.25cm]

      \tikzset{decision/.style={
        draw=gray-5-border, solid, fill=gray-e-bg, rectangle, 
        anchor=north,
        inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0, text centered, growth parent anchor=south} 
      }
      \tikzset{prediction/.style={
        draw=gray-4-border, solid, fill=gray-d-bg, ellipse, 
        anchor=north,
        inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0, text centered, growth parent anchor=south} 
      }
      \tikzset{arrow/.style={-latex, thick}}
      \tikzset{arrow-dashed/.style={-latex, dashed, thick}}

      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [prediction] {+0.5} [dashed, -latex, thick, ->]
          child { 
            node [decision] {$a < 4.5$} [->]
              child {
                node [prediction] {-0.7} [solid, -latex, thick, ->] 
                  child {
                    node [decision] {$b > 1$} [dashed, -latex, thick, ->]
                      child {
                        node [prediction] {+0.4} [solid, -latex, thick, ->]
                      }
                      child {
                        node [prediction] {-0.2} [solid, -latex, thick, ->]
                      }
                  }
                  child {
                    node [decision] {$a > 2$} [dashed, -latex, thick, ->]
                      child {
                        node [prediction] {-0.1} [solid, -latex, thick, ->]
                      }
                      child {
                        node [prediction] {+0.1} [solid, -latex, thick, ->]
                      }
                  }
              }
              child {
                node [prediction] {+0.2} [solid, -latex, thick, ->]
              }
          }
          child {
            node [decision] {$b > 0$}
              child {
                node [prediction] {+0.3} [solid, -latex, thick, ->]
              }
              child {
                node [prediction] {-0.6} [solid, -latex, thick, ->]
              }
          }
        ;
      \end{tikzpicture}

      \caption{A diagram of Freund and Mason's general alternating decision tree}
      \label{fig:diagram-adt}
    \end{figure}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You need to use `node [prediction {$-0.7$} edge from parent [dashed, -latex, thick] node [near end, right] {Yes}`. Note that I also have used math-mode for `-0.7` so that the minus sign will be typeset correct. I also removed `->` because you already had `-latex` in there, the `->` will overwrite the `-latex` with `-to`. And please use the `edge from parent` style to include at least `-latex, thick` so you don’t need to repeat that everytime.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel - thank you very much. I am genuinely sorry and I will take note of that next time I ask a question here. 

I was able to apply your solution but what happened is the two child nodes' arrows were misplaced and these arrows are now directed south of the newly added `{Yes}` node. How do I solve this?

Comment: I just used `node [near start, right, yshift=0.25cm] {Y} node [prediction] {$-0.7$} edge from parent [solid, -latex, thick]`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: will there be an upvoted answer for this problem? This is not an unanswered question, but it is indeed listed as one...

Comment: what was the final code for this - i.e. what packages were included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
node [prediction {$-0.7$} edge from parent [dashed] node [near end, right] {Yes}
```

I’d also add `-latex, thick` to the `edge from parent` so that you don’t have to repeat common options every time.

I also removed `->` from the options because you already had `-latex` in there, the `->` will overwrite the `-latex´ with`-to`(or to whatever`>` is set).

Note that I also have used math-mode for `-0.7` so that the minus sign will be typeset correctly (it is advisory to use `text depth=+0pt` for the nodes because the minus sign adds a certain depth, but so does the `+`).